# Knockout Mapping and boolean values

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am using knockout and knockout mapping fromJS to map to my observablearray.

I'm calling a service method to return my json data to map to 
The db behind my service call has a column that is boolean true/false and right now that's the value that is pulling into my grid.

Is there a way to transform the value from true/false to something else like Active/Inactive

if So how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.  Found it.  Simply need to set a values observableArray to my column defined in the grid.

VM JS file

```
self.statusValues = [{ value: true, text: 'Active' }, { value: false, text: 'Inactive' }];
```

In the view

```
values: statusValues
            }
```